# How to get time elapsed till 12:00 AM in same day and rest on next day

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

I am currently facing difficulty to calculate exact hours between In Time and Out time.

for instance :

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-1-2022 | 10:00 PM | 1-2-2022 | 6:00 AM |
| 1-2-2022 | 10:00 PM | 1-3-2022 | 6:00 AM |

Now, my problem is that I have to calculate the time from 10:00 PM till 12:00 AM = 2 Hours and rest to be calculated on the next day adding the previous days hours e.g. we have 6 hours from 12:00 AM till 6:00 AM for 1-2-2022 (Column C) and then 2 hours from 10:00 PM to 12:00 AM.

Looking forward your help.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the date and times together, subtracting the In time from the Out time.

[image]

Comment: But you are giving me complete 8 hours on column E for 1/1/2022 and 2/1/2022 however; I want a formula which should return 2 hours for 1/1/2022 and 6 hours for 2/1/2022 and when we will fill down the formula then it should check if in date is yesterday’s out date; if it is so; then it will sum up the hours i.e. 8 hours for 2/1/2022 (out hours : 6) on 1st Row and then (in hours 2) on 2nd Row. I hope; I’m able to explain what exactly I’m looking for

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different method:

[image]

B2, D2 and E2 formatted as hh:mm

Then you could use mod() like so:

```
=MOD(D2-B2,1)
```

Comment: But you are giving me complete 8 hours on column E for 1/1/2022 and 2/1/2022 however; I want a formula which should return 2 hours for 1/1/2022 and 6 hours for 2/1/2022 and when we will fill down the formula then it should check if in date is yesterday’s out date; if it is so; then it will sum up the hours i.e. 8 hours for 2/1/2022 (out hours : 6) on 1st Row and then (in hours 2) on 2nd Row. I hope; I’m able to explain what exactly I’m looking for

Comment: @NaveenTamta so take the method I show and efit it to do two parts which is easy then add them. I did it this way as it is one step., as for the dates you could use an if() to check the dates are consecutive and then do the calc I suggest.