# How does one calculates the difference in time in an excel pivottable?

Tags: excel, time, pivot-table

I am creating a timeregistry and have created a sample in a pivottable in excel. I start out with a list of actions that occured per day per person. I made a pivottable grouped by day and person.

I would like to have a Grand Total column that calculates the difference in time per person per day --- and a Grand Total row at the bottom that calculates the average of the values in that column

Currently, I take the max of time, because that way, at least most of the field are correctly filled. However, the Grand Total column and row do not behave as I desire. I have tried multiple "things" using the PivotTable Analyze -> Fields, Items & Sets and Calculated Fields, but all to no avail. (I had also added a column next to the pivottable to calculate the Grand Total, but when dragging down, the date value remains the same. After which I have added the values manually) Could someone please help me?

```
person  date    time    action
person a    06/06/2022  08:00:00    in
person a    06/06/2022  19:00:00    out
person b    06/06/2022  10:00:00    in
person b    06/06/2022  18:00:00    out
person a    07/06/2022  08:00:00    in
person a    07/06/2022  19:00:00    out
person b    07/06/2022  10:00:00    in
person b    07/06/2022  18:00:00    out
person a    08/06/2022  08:00:00    in
person a    08/06/2022  19:00:00    out
person b    08/06/2022  10:00:00    in
person b    08/06/2022  18:00:00    out
person a    09/06/2022  08:00:00    in
person a    09/06/2022  19:00:00    out
person b    09/06/2022  10:00:00    in
person b    09/06/2022  18:00:00    out
person a    10/06/2022  08:00:00    in
person a    10/06/2022  19:00:00    out
person b    10/06/2022  10:00:00    in
person b    10/06/2022  18:00:00    out
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you calculated the results outside of pivottable? Ie just in a cell for each person? There are examples of time calculations on here.

Comment: Perhaps see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72410301/4961700

Comment: yes, I have calculated the desired values per cell. I have searched for answers, but have not found a seemingly simple calculation as this in a pivottable. The catch is that the pivottable is sort of required to get the time in and out stacked the way they are in a simple manner, which complicates further calculations